# How can I get a gitlab pipeline to stop and ask me to input variables?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a pipeline in gitlab, with

```
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

variables:
  PLAN: dbrest.tfplan
  STATE: dbrest.tfstate

cache:
  paths:
    - .terraform

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

stages:
  - validate
  - build
  - deploy
  - destroy

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate

plan:
  stage: build
  script:
    - terraform plan -state=$STATE -out=$PLAN
  artifacts:
    name: plan
    paths:
      - $PLAN
      - $STATE

apply:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - terraform apply -state=$STATE -input=false $PLAN
    - terraform state show aws_instance.bastion
  dependencies:
    - plan
  when: manual
  only:
    - master

destroy:
    stage: destroy
    environment:
      name: production
    script:
      - terraform destroy -state=$STATE -auto-approve
    dependencies:
      - apply
    when: manual
    only:
      - master
```

I have also created a variable under 'Settings. -> 'CI/CD' -> 'Variables' - I was under the impression that when I came to the manual stage `deploy`, gitlab should pause and ask me to input a value for that variable, but this does not happen - what is missing?

Comment: Looks like this is documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#environment-variables-triggered-manually).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have mixed a job with `when: manual` to when you trigger a pipeline manually. This is the one you want:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#run-a-pipeline-manually

You could use this together with an `only` for some variable. Something like:

```
...
apply:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - terraform apply -state=$STATE -input=false $PLAN
    - terraform state show aws_instance.bastion
  dependencies:
    - plan
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    variables:
      - $RELEASE == "yes" 

destroy:
    stage: destroy
    environment:
      name: production
    script:
      - terraform destroy -state=$STATE -auto-approve
    dependencies:
      - apply
    only:
      refs:
        - master
      variables:
        - $RELEASE == "yes"
```

With something like this, you can have jobs that are never run normally, but only if you manually start a new pipeline on the master branch and set the variable `$RELEASE` to `yes`. I haven't tested this, so my apologies if it doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, that was it! Now, it would be handy if gitlab would list the variables I want to set at this point - there doesn't seem to be any syntax for specifying 'ask for these variables'. You can't have everything, I suppose.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n, variables enumerate as environment variables, so try adding `set` as the first command in the script where you want to see them.

Comment: You can do this now. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines  make sure you define a description and value, it doesn't seem to work with just a value.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment and I still think there's more needed for a complete answer, but I do believe this will work for what you're asking for. I included what I've used in the past as well, "MODE" but then you'd need to update the Rules section on your jobs to reflect when you wanted the job to run based on MODE vs RELEASE

```
variables:
  PLAN: dbrest.tfplan
  STATE: dbrest.tfstate
  RELEASE:
    description: "Provide YES or NO to trigger jobs"
    default: "NO"
  MODE:
    description: "Actions for terraform to perform, ie: PLAN, APPLY, DESTROY, PLAN_APPLY, ALL"
    default: "PLAN"
```